# GET was unable to find an engine to execute this computation

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I am trying to fine tune the "Segment Anything" model released by Facebook. Specifically, I am trying to tune a fork of the model that has some code for fine-tuning on medical images, termed MedSAM (found [here](https://github.com/bowang-lab/MedSAM)). When trying to run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/beegfs/khans24/medsam_finetuning/minimal.py", line 30, in <module>
    embedding = sam_model.image_encoder(input_image)
  File "/home/khans24/beegfs/miniconda/envs/sam/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/beegfs/khans24/segment-anything/segment_anything/modeling/image_encoder.py", line 107, in forward
    x = self.patch_embed(x)
  File "/home/khans24/beegfs/miniconda/envs/sam/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/beegfs/khans24/segment-anything/segment_anything/modeling/image_encoder.py", line 392, in forward
    x = self.proj(x)
  File "/home/khans24/beegfs/miniconda/envs/sam/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/khans24/beegfs/miniconda/envs/sam/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 463, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/home/khans24/beegfs/miniconda/envs/sam/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 459, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: GET was unable to find an engine to execute this computation
```

I've tried to troubleshoot this many times by switching with different CUDA and cuDNN versions, but to no avail. Here are the specs of the system I am running it on:

- PyTorch 2.0 (but also tried with 1.13)
- Runtime CUDA 11.0
- Runtime cuDNN 8.2.1

Output of `torch.backends.cudnn.version()` is `8500`
I get positive results from running the following code:

```
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
print(torch.backends.cudnn.enabled)
print(torch.backends.cudnn.version())
```

Output is `True, 4, True, 8500`

I am also running this on a high-performance computing cluster, the OS is RedHat Linux. I am also using the "modules" package to load in the CUDA toolkit from modulefiles. I have limited ability to install things since I do not have root access.

Here is also a minimal reproducible example:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, transform
from segment_anything import SamPredictor, sam_model_registry
from segment_anything.utils.transforms import ResizeLongestSide

# Set up the model and device
model_type = 'vit_b'
checkpoint = 'load/medsam_20230423_vit_b_0.0.1.pth'
device = 'cuda:0'

sam_model = sam_model_registry[model_type](checkpoint=checkpoint).to(device)

# Generate a random image
image_size = 256
random_image = np.random.randint(0, 256, (image_size, image_size, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Resize the random image
sam_transform = ResizeLongestSide(sam_model.image_encoder.img_size)
resized_image = sam_transform.apply_image(random_image)

# Convert the resized image to a PyTorch tensor
resized_image_tensor = torch.as_tensor(resized_image.transpose(2, 0, 1)).to(device)

# Preprocess the image tensor
input_image = sam_model.preprocess(resized_image_tensor[None, :, :, :])

# Compute the image embedding using the sam_model
with torch.no_grad():
    embedding = sam_model.image_encoder(input_image)
    print(embedding.shape)
```

Any help is appreciated.